# Images take time and get loaded after loading text contents on my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want my images to be loaded fast as HTML and CSS get loaded.
As of now HTML and CSS don't take time but loading images (all are in .svg format and small) take more than 2 seconds after other content.

Is there a way to load them faster?

I found answers regarding fast-loading and followed as well, which are:

`-compress images`

`-Minify HTML and JS files`

But my issue is still unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually considered a good practice to load images after all contents of a webpage. You could try with the following-

- Clear the cache or try in Incognito and different browsers and devices to check if the issue pertains.
- Store the images for faster loading times in AWS or similar services.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the way the pages are loading is normal.

If you can't decrease your file sizes any more, you might be interested in showing a highly compressed version while your full sized image loads:

```html
<img border="0" style="background:url(https://i.imgur.com/ML9NHOA.jpg) no-repeat; width:727px; height:484px" src="https://i.imgur.com/Zp8a50J.jpg" width="727" height="484" />
```

In the above snippet, a 25kb image quickly loads and is shown while the 700kb image is still loading. You can watch the process in action by disabling cache and throttling your connection speed in the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

1. angular js loads script and style that are ready to load and with no errors, and load error later.
2. if the image size is big it surely would load slow, high resolution images tends to load slow.
3. are you using external script and style in your code, like fonts, jquery or any other framework, try load them locally to improve site speed.
4. local servers like xamp, wamp etc loads base on system speed , so you cant judge else you are on production stage.
5. you are right minified version could work.

alternative

big sites like facebok, yahoo and google, uses site.loader to check if all site content is loaded and two if loaded display all site content.

since you are using js, check if all script are up to date and no one is using outdated function

check for errors in console .

limit your use of image.

hope that was helpful.